# How to render a table with mixed geometry types in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, postgis

I created a table with geometry type "GEOMETRY" AND inserted data of point, line and polygon type. My question is how to show this spatial data Qgis not supporting for geometry type "GEOMETRY".

Comment: QGIS can only render one geometry type per layer.

Answer (score 12):

Create distinct tables for each spatial feature, e.g. a table for point(s), a table for line(s), and a table for polygon(s). Then you can load these spatial tables as PostGIS layers.

There is also a ticket regarding this issue: http://trac.osgeo.org/qgis/ticket/167

It seems like it could be fixed only in QGIS 2.0.

Comment: Or if you wanna have a common table for your different geometry types - there are such use cases - you could create views using GeometryType for filtering. Though I'm not sure how QGIS will infer the geometry type.