# How to Create database using OGC compliant geometries and Custom type Geometries?

Tags: postgis, spatial-database, ogc

I am interested in storing geometry attributes in a PostGis database, so that it would be OGC compliant, along with OGC compliant geometry types like point,line, linestring, etc. I also wanted to store some custom type geometry types like ellipse,circle,arrow,some symbols (also combinations of these types) etc, these custom geometry types have different attributes(entities).

Is it possible to store all these geometry in a Generic OGC compliant DataBase?

I'm using pdf file "URL:http://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=829"(99-049_OpenGIS_Simple_Features_Specification_For_SQL_Rev_1.1.pdf) as a reference, and as per page 2-20, it appears like I can represent any kind of geometry using GEOMETRY_COLUMNS, SPATIAL_REFERENCE_SYSTEMS, FeatureTables and GEOMETRY_COLUMNS. But a lot of the geometries I have are custom created - like thick curved arrows with control points to allow a user to adjust the curvature of the arrow, and a text label at the center of the arrow, polygons with an X mark at the center of every edge and control points at certain points of the polygon to allow the user to resize it etc.

like i have n no:of item(custom_geometries like,arrow,symbols etc)each item has unique attributes.
should i create multiple feature table for each item?

Comment: For sure, thats what these database types are made for...what is your question actually? The latter types you mentioned (arrow, symbols) are not part of the OGC Simple Features Specification as far as I know.

Comment: From the title, I think he's asking about geometries which can be drawn on the screen and edited by the user at runtime and later stored as a layer of dynamic geometries, in a postgis database when the application's workspace is saved. Something like this would typically require control points and handles to be stored with the geometry, which isn't (as per my knowledge) supported directly by OGC. (at least I'd like to know) How would such dynamic data be stored in a database?

Comment: Hi prem: welcome to gis.SE. To help us answer the question, can you edit it (just click edit above) to provide some more details. You can easily add whatever you want as blobs to the database, but that isn't usually what you want. Instead, you want to do some action - display, query, summarise. If you can tell us more about what you're trying to do with this data, it might help a lot.

Comment: ya exactly....and i also wanted to maintain single schema for both (custom) dynamic data and OGC geometry types.

Comment: Similar question (not duplicate though): http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/38863/how-to-render-a-table-with-mixed-geometry-types-in-qgis?rq=1